# What database engine should I use?

Tags: web-development, server, mysql, database, sql

I don't know if this is the right place to ask this question but I want to become a web programmer for my occupation very soon. I actually went to a store known a PC WORLD in the UK where my laptop wasn't working. Anyway the person on the counter was talking to me about certain thing and then he found out that I am currently doing web and database programming in my master studies.

Now he has a mobile repair website but he hasn't got a database. He is thinking of calling me in the future as he really wants a database created for his website. I always like a challenge so I think I will probably agree to do this job for him.

But what my question is that first of all, if a person already has it's own website and he wants me to create a database for him, then which server do I use, do I use the server he currently has or is it up to me to find a server to link to.

Second what is the best database software to use, he said he is thinking of using Access which I said to him don't do it on Access. I was thinking of using either Oracle or MYSQL but I think Oracle is expensive, I don't know about MySQL. I am thinking of using PHP to link between his website and the database.

Third of all if somebody asked you to create a database for a small business website, how much would you charge that person. What is a reasonable price?

Thank You (If this is not right place to ask this question, can you please tell me which stack exchange site I should go on to ask this question. Also which correct tags can I use for this question)

Comment: What would the requirement be for the database (on the website)? Just curious as the _client_ suggested Access. Ok, the _client_ might not have an idea about web development technologies, but then again, maybe it is really a desktop application (contacts/works database) they are after? Just a thought.

Answer (score 3):

[MySQL](http://www.mysql.com/) is free, well documented and supported, and absolutely scalable for any reasonably-sized business need. It is a secure, mature system. If this is going to be your first real-life application with a database, I'd start with that one. There's no point in choosing Oracle or any paid option for a small mobile repair website — unless, of course, you are the mobile phone provider yourself.